# How to use map in groovy

Tags: groovy

Here is how my script currently looks like -

```
baseList = readFile('text2.txt').split('\n') as List
def cleanList = []
for (i=0; i < baseList.size; i++) {
   if (baseList[i].contains('=')){
     cleanList += baseList[i]
   }
}
print(cleanList)
```

This gives following output-

```
[Pipeline] echo
[version.build=874, version.maintenance=0, version.major=1, version.minor=37]
```

I want these values to go into another variable called "svnTag"

```
def svnTag="ccsmp_v_${version.major} ${version.minor} ${version.maintenance} ${version.build}"
```

So that when I print svnTag, it output something like this-

```
SVN_TAG=ccsmp_v_1.37.0.846
```

Comment: Is the line in the file that has the version info always the second line or does your solution need to inspect each line to find the one with the version info?

Comment: Is `[Pipeline] echo` the first line in `text2.txt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using a `Map`, but a `List` of `String`, where each element is in the form of `<key>=<value>`

If you want to parse your file to a Map, you could use something like:

```
def baseList = readFile('text2.txt').split('\n') as List
def map = [:]
for (el in baseList) {
    if (el.contains('=')) {
        def parts = el.split('=')
        map[parts[0]] = parts[1]
    }
}
```

Then you can use the values from the map with:

```
def svnTag="ccsmp_v_${map['version.major']} ${map['version.minor']} ${map['version.maintenance']} ${map['version.build']}"
```

If your file is a valid property file (all lines are in form of `key=value`), you can use the `readProperties` step that will create a Properties object for you (that is in fact a `Map`):

```
def map = readProperties file: 'text2.txt'
```